# How to repair a broken surface in vtk?

Tags: graphics, computational-geometry, vtk

I'm sure that an average vtk user already has seen results like the following more than once.

[image: Broken surface of a 3D model]

My question(s): How would you repair such a broken surface? And what is typically the cause for such wholes in the surface?

My particular example was created by using vtkBooleanOperationPolyDataFilter and vtkAppendPolyData, but I've seen such broken, degenerate surfaces also in different occasions.

Many thanks for suggestions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the case I presented above, the broken surface was caused by problems with the `vtkBooleanOperationPolyDataFilter`. According to [this](http://vtk.1045678.n5.nabble.com/vtkBooleanOperationPolyDataFilter-creates-non-manifold-edges-td5738088.html) thread, the algorithm has been improved and is (or will soon be) made available in a newer release of vtk.

I also need to accept the fact that there is no general recipe to recover from such failures in vtk, and, as mirni pointed out, are data-related.

Answer (score 2):

This is most likely data-related. Suggestions:

- Many vtk filters have assumptions about the inputs, and I am guessing your inputs violated some of these assumptions. E.g. `vtkBooleanOperationPolyDataFilter` expects inputs to be manifolds, otherwise "unexpected results may be obtained". What are you feeding into the boolean filter? Are these inputs manifolds?
- Some other filters have much stricter requirements and expect only triangulated surfaces; in the image you posted I *think* I see quads. Try to run the inputs through `vtkTriangleFilter` at the beginning of your processing pipeline to split all polys into triangles.
- Inspect the second output of `vtkBooleanOperationPolyDataFilter` which contains the intersection as set of polylines, for any hints on what could be the cause of this.
- Try to save the intermediate results into a file and expect them at different stages in your processing pipeline.

If none of this will lead you to the cause of the problem, please post the inputs, the code and vtk version and system that you are running it on, so that we can reproduce your results.

HTH,

Miro

Comment: @Miro. Thanks for the suggestions. The input data is manifold, I do use vtkTriangleFilter and I also inspected the second output of vtkBooleanOperationPolyDataFilter. For now I belief it's a (possibly numerical) flaw in vtkBooleanOperationPoyDataFilter, as it shows up only sometimes. I've posted the problem [here](http://vtk.1045678.n5.nabble.com/Broken-surfaces-for-vtkBooleanOperationPolyDataFilter-Bug-td5735413.html) on the vtk mailing list to let the dev team know about it.

Comment: @Miro. I hoped to get a general recipe on how to fix such broken surfaces a posteriori. Some tools have a "mesh doctor" functionality for this purpose, and I wondered how such this could be done in vtk.

Comment: There is vtkFillHolesFilter that can stitch the tears but your mileage may vary.
I noticed in the code you posted on mailing list that you actually don't use the trianglefilter in operation2 so it might be worth plugging in sourceTriangles instead of source. 
Also, you might want to decrease or increase the tolerance somewhat -- depending on the scale of your data this may make a difference.

Comment: See vtkBooleanOperationPolyDataFilter::SetTolerance(double)